# Call a method on a nested controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an Angular app that displays a ui.bootstrap.modal dialog when I click on a certain element. I want to make the modal logic reusable so have separated it into a separate controller. The result (simplified) looks like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <button class="btn" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
    <div ng-controller="ModalController" modal="shouldBeOpen" close="close()" options="opts">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

The visibility of the modal is controlled by a property on ModalController:

```
$scope.shouldBeOpen = true;
```

How can I set that property from the `open()` method on `MyController`?

Comment: Are you using the `$dialog` service?  If so then you can open the modal by using the `dialog` method and passing in a view and controller.  See [the wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/dialog/README.md#dialog-service)

Comment: Thanks @NuclearGhost, came across it after writing this post. Looks like the way to go.